# Finding the package named "multiprocessing" in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, multiprocessing, common-lisp, practical-common-lisp

I am working with SBCL (SBCL 1.2.13.84-7d75f89) learning Common Lisp from this [book](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/). I have run into a problem, trying to find and load the package named `multiprocessing`.

([This is in Chapter 29 of the book](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-an-mp3-browser.html))

I have tried doing `(ql:system-apropos "multiprocessing")`, `(ql:system-apropos "thread")`, `(ql:system-apropos "smp")` trying to see if there is a quicklisp package that uses it.

I have also searched using google, and even at [Quickdocs](http://quickdocs.org/) but I seem to be failing somewhere.

I would be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: The chapter says "Finally, the lock slot holds a process lock created with the function make-process-lock, which is part of Allegro's MULTIPROCESSING package. ", so I guess you would have to use Allegro for that. Or implement the necessary features yourself.

Comment: Looking over the chapter, it seems like the `with-process-lock` and `make-process-lock` are pretty much identical to sbcl's [`with-mutex`](http://sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Mutex-Support) and `make-mutex`. You could also use [bordeaux threads](https://trac.common-lisp.net/bordeaux-threads/wiki/ApiDocumentation) which has `make-lock` and `with-lock-held` that should do the same thing as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [example in the book](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-an-mp3-browser.html) uses the web server AllegroServe from Franz Inc. and the corresponding Allegro Common Lisp (ACL). ACL has a package named `multiprocessing` which provides the needed multiprocessing facilities.

The book proposes to use [PortableAllegroServe](http://portableaserve.sourceforge.net) for those who don't use Allegro Common Lisp. See [chapter 26](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-web-programming-with-allegroserve.html) in the book.

PortableAllegroServe has a package named `acl-compat.mp`, which provides the necessary functionality in a portable way. For example `acl-compat.mp:with-process-lock`, `acl-compat.mp:make-process-lock`, ...

You thus need to either

- AllegroServe and Allegro Common Lisp
- PortableAllegroServe and a Common Lisp implementation it runs in

The names of the packages will be slightly different, though.

Note that this chapter is one which might need some updating. I'm not sure how much PortableAllegroServe is used these days...

Comment: Thanks. I'd already tried using the idea presented in jkiiski comment on [bordeaux threads](https://trac.common-lisp.net/bordeaux-threads/wiki/ApiDocumentation) and that worked. I also played around in slime with the acl-compat.mp and it seems to also work.